# Turtle object appearing twice on screen, one with no functionality python Turtle

Tags: python

I am working on a snake game using the python Turtle module. I am at the stage of creating the food for the snake to collect now and when I run the game there is always 2 pieces of food on screen while I only want one. One of these foods are also not obtainable and doesn't add score to the game it is just simply there.
Here is the class i used to create the food and below is the game loop. The 'food' object is that of he class Food().

```
class Food(Turtle):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    
        self.shape('circle')
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=0.5,stretch_wid=0.5)
        self.color('blue')
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.refresh()
        
    def refresh(self):
       random_x = random.randint(-280,280)
       random_y = random.randint(-280,280)
       self.goto(random_x,random_y) 
    while running:
        screen.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        snake.move()
    
        if snake.head.distance(food) < 15:
            food.refresh()
            score.increase()
```

I have tried .clear() and the .refresh() functions after the initialization but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are accidentally creating 2 instances of "food" in your app. You can use print statement to check this.

You can add a print statement to the **init** method of the food class to see if food if getting called more than once. You can also try adding a print statement to the refresh section of your code to check if the food is getting refreshed twice.

If all fails, you could add code to your while loop that would remove the extra food:

```
# Remove extra food object, if it exists
for obj in screen.turtles():
    if obj != food and obj.distance(snake.head) < 15:
        obj.clear()
        obj.ht()
```

You could add this code to the buttom of your while loop. Good luck :)